# how to use several animation property in CSS3 without stop ? (just use CSS3)

Tags: css, css-animations

this is my code and i want this 3 animation repeat infinite. i can put animation property in style="" but those animations are played just once ! and if i set animation property to infinite, div a and div c animation combine together and this is not what i want !

i want : first. play a , second. play b and then. play c and reapet this 
3 mission in infinite loop !

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>

$u = 1

@-webkit-while $u == 1
{
.all .a {-webkit-animation : a 10s linear 0s;}
.all .b {-webkit-animation : b 10s linear 10s;}
.all .c {-webkit-animation : c 10s linear 20s;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes a {from {width:5px;} to {width:500px;}}
@-webkit-keyframes b {from {background-color:blue;} to {background-color:yellow;}}
@-webkit-keyframes c {from {opacity:0;} to {opacity:1;}}

</style>
<body>

<div class="all">
<div class="a" style="position:relative; background-color:red; width:5px; height:500px;"></div>

<div class="b" style="position:relative; background-color:blue; width:500px; height:500px;"></div>

<div class="c" style="position:relative; background-color:green; width:500px; height:500px; opacity:0;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks for your help...

Comment: not that this is the cause, but spell `position:rel a tive` correctly

Comment: is this closer to what you wish: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JW7Gv/)

Comment: cm1 : yes position relative is correct. tnx ;) but my problem is not this case.

Comment: cm2 : thank u. i wrote and used this code but when u run this code , class a and class b (or a with c) animations combine together after first loop. i want this loop : animate a (start-end) -> animate b (start-end) -> animate c (start-end) and then repeat this loop forever. when one class animate, 2 other class wait ! / @fnostro

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bBYbj/ look this. @fnostro

Comment: I do not know if that can be done with pure CSS, my knowledge of CSS3 animation is minimal.  If jquery/jqueryui is an option it could be done by chaining calls to jquery.animate().  (NB: jqueryui would be required to animate the background color.)